# How do I download audio resources and cache them?

Tags: unity, memory

I am developing a game in Unity 2019. The instructions of the game must be translated into several languages. Currently they are part of the compilation, but this makes the compilation very large.

I would like, according to the selected language, to be able to download the corresponding audio and cache it.

Comment: What have you tried? Have you searched about downloading assets using Unity? That way you can use them the same way as local assets.

Comment: Hello @TomTsagk. The resources that I use are the ones that I have in the project, I need to be able to download the audio resources remotely and that they are stored in the device so as not to have to download them again, but I have not found documentation on this.

Comment: I just searched for "Unity download remote file" and got plenty of promising results. Did any of them work for you?

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but the current official best practice is to use Unity's [`Addressable Asset System`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.addressables@0.4/manual/index.html) to manage and asynchronously load asset packages from any location and with any collection of dependencies. The addressable system is built on top of `AssetBundles`, and while a bit of a steep learning curve at first, in my experience it is flexible and robust in action.

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW-audioClip.html
https://forum.unity.com/threads/download-and-save-www-mp3-file.409470/

these are what you are looking for. but WWW is being deprecated. just try to find **UnityHttpRequest** replacement solution for this. in these threads you problem is dicussed well.

you can check if you have that file in your device. if there isnt, so you have to get it from server.

Comment: This answer would benefit from a working example or walkthrough of the process to create one, rather than just links to the component parts.

Comment: I would recommend using an AssetBundle instead of downloading individual audio clips, partly because Unity has AssetBundle caching built in.

Comment: @EdMarty yes.  good suggestion. you can update the answer if you want.